# How a BHO add-in can communicate with a process in .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, named-pipes, bho

I have developed in c# 2 applications: a desktop application which runs from windows sturtup and a BHO add-on for Internet Explorer.I want the add-on to call a method of the running application once an event is triggered in the add-on.I have tried with NamedPipes ,but System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream cannot be found in BHO add-on.Exactly the Pipes namespace does not exist in System.IO namespace. 
Any Idea how to realize the communication by mean of namedpipes or anything else??

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? System.IO.Pipes should be there in .NET 3.5 and later (assuming you didn't remove the reference to System.Core or something like that).

Comment: thank you .i am using  .NET 3.5.The problem is I cannot add the System.Core reference to the BHO add-on project

Comment: If you originally created it as a .NET 3.5 project, then the reference to System.Core should have already been there. Did you remove it, or did you upgrade this project from an earlier version of .NET? And when you say "cannot add the System.Core reference", what do you mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what was it? I can't read minds.

Comment: BHO browser add-on project is not like every other project.When I open the Add Reference Window the System.Core is frozzen probably because this is a browser project.

Comment: It may be good idea to add a note on the place where you did get this "BHO add-on" project/project template from. 3.5 and "no System.Core" sounds strange together...

Comment: you are right man.the target framework version was 2.0 I changed to 3.5 in project properties and it works excellently now.I appreciate very much your guidelines.